# Зависит ли от реализации языка программирования возможность создать для него альтернативную реализацию?

Tags: компиляция, интерпретатор, трансляция

Возможно ли для интерпретируемого языка программирования написать компилятор? На основе интерпретатора или с нуля.
И наоборот, скажем, реализовать интерпретатор для компилируемого Go или C++
Или же есть критические моменты, не позволяющие сделать это?

Comment: Сам язык всего лишь набор символов в файлах. Для Java есть JVM, которая понимает файлы байткода `.class` скомпилированные компилятором, но в то же время, этот байткод интерпретируется в JVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дам кусочек [отсюда](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%A2%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%83#:%7E:text=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D0%A2%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%83%20%E2%80%94%20%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F,%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D1%91%D0%BC%20%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%8E%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%8E%20%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E.)

Полнота по Тьюрингу — характеристика исполнителя (множества вычисляющих элементов) в теории вычислимости, означающая возможность реализовать на нём любую вычислимую функцию. Другими словами, для каждой вычислимой функции существует вычисляющий её элемент (например, машина Тьюринга) или программа для исполнителя, а все функции, вычисляемые множеством вычислителей, являются вычислимыми функциями (возможно, при некотором кодировании входных и выходных данных).

Большинство широко используемых языков программирования — тьюринг-полные.

Ну и ответ на ваш вопрос.

Возможно ли для интерпретируемого языка программирования написать компилятор? - да если он Тьюринг полный.

Comment: Формулировка _"Большинство широко используемых языков программирования..."_ - предполагает, что среди них есть хотя бы один не тьюринг-полный. Жутко интересно, какой. :)

Comment: @Yaant - препроцессор языка C https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor

Comment: @gbg спасибо :)

Answer (score 2):

Компилятор-то написать можно, но не факт, что это приведет к серьезному ускорению кода без сокращения возможностей языка.

Например, если язык активно использует интроспекцию или меняет текст программы на ходу, все что останется сделать - это сложить интерпретатор и исходник программы в один файл и сказать, что так и было.